# How to use Cassandra on-node storage engine only?

Tags: java, database-design, nosql, cassandra, hdfs

I am developing an application for data storage. All the replication, routing and data retrieving types of business are handled in my application. Up to now, the data is stored in memory. Now, I want to used Cassandra storage engine to flush data from memory into hard drive. I am not sure if that is a correct approach.

My question:
Can i use the Cassandra data storage engine only? I do not want to use Cassandra as a whole system (In this case, I should run one independent Cassandra per node and my application act as if it is `client` of Cassandra. This idea will put a lot of on node since it puts unnecessary levels between my application and storage engine).

I have my own replication,  ring and routing code. I only need the on-node storage facilities of Cassandra.

Comment: Cassandra is a "storage engine". What do you mean? Do you mean that you want to run Cassandra in an "embedded" mode, so the users do not have to start and control Cassandra processes and write Cassandra configuration files?

Comment: Yes. I want to embed cassandra in my application. I have my own replication, ring and routing mechanisms. I want cassandra only store my data in local storage per node. That is all I want. I looked into cassandra's source code, I found a directory called "db" Do you think it contains necessary classes to store data?

Comment: I mean I want to import Cassandra as a library and use its skills. In my case, only its database feature.

Answer (score 1):

The Cassandra developers have not gone out of their way to make it easy to use Cassandra as an embedded library rather than a standalone product. Contrast with Apache Derby, which is very easy to embed. But it is possible to do it; I have done so, and it was not an enormous task.

You will have to study the source code to locate the bits you need. I don't know the specific bits of interest to you, but to locate them you will have to learn about some parts of the code that use those bits but which are not of direct interest to you.

To provide a convenient API and to provide a configuration interface you might have to replace some Cassandra classes with modified versions. This is impractical without a good build and version control system. I use Maven for building, and found its Shade plug-in helpful for creating a JAR that contained most, but not all, of the Cassandra classses, with selective replacement of some classes.